# AngularJS - call function after text field completion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text field as

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputID" name="inputName" ng-model="inputUserName" ng-required="true" autofocus="true"/>
```

Once I input the text value and say, press Tab, or move on to the next field, I want to call a function which basically takes the input value and sends it to my server API to perform a validity check. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the ng-blur:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="method()">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur